# error in loop with for "python open document"

Tags: python, libreoffice

I'm follow this tutorial [appy.pod](http://appyframework.org/podWritingTemplates.html) and I'm creating a list of dict more or less something like this:

```
params['reports'] = [{'date': foo.date, 'name': foo.name} for foo in something]
```

and in the libreoffice - writer i have a note with this

```
do text for foo in reports
```

and when I excecute the code I get this error

`Syntax error while parsing a note whose content is "[]". In a note, you may specify at most 2 lines: a pod statement and a "from" clause. A Pod statement has the form: do {element} [{command} {expression}]. {element} identifies the part of the document that will be impacted by the command. It must be one of ('text', 'title', 'section', 'table', 'row', 'cell'). Optional {command} can be "if" (conditional inclusion of the element) or "for" (multiple inclusion of the element). For an "if" command, {expression} is any Python expression. For a "for" command, {expression} must be of the form: {name} in {expression}. {name} must be a Python variable name. It is the name of the iteration variable. {expression} is a Python expression that, when evaluated, produces a Python sequence (tuple, string, list, etc). A "from" clause has the form: from {expression}, where {expression} is a Python expression that, when evaluated, produces a valid chunk of odt content that will be inserted instead of the element that is the target of the note.`

to make a note, is necessary active the 'track changes' mode?

there is another question related but that do not work for me
[Comments are seen as empty, even though they're not](https://answers.launchpad.net/appy/+question/139478)

somebody can help me, what I have wrong

Comment: That's an actual error message? Wow.

Comment: @NPE yes that can be seen in the report already generated in libreoffice Writer

Comment: That was an expression of amazement rather than disbelief :)

Comment: for me pod runs very nice. it is easy make reports, you can use libreoffice or OO as a WYSIWYG report editor. it is not necessary to active the 'track changes' mode to write pod code in Comments. Let OO doc and source code available to review.

Comment: with your posted data I have not enough information to isolate issue. But, perhaps, you should replace `do text for foo in reports` by `do text for foo in params.reports`

Comment: Also, don't install pod from pip or easy_install. Download the project and include it by hand in your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is here [appy forum](https://answers.launchpad.net/appy/+question/224843)

> What pod version do you use?
>   Note that, on Pypi, packages appy.pod and appy.shared are deprecated. Use new package appy.
>   Gaetan

That I did was install pod with pip install and offcourse is deprecated, so you have to download the appy from here [Download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appy) and copy the "appy" folder from appy.xxx.zip to the "site-packages" folder of your Python interpreter.

Comment: the hand-install is unnecessary, as the main developer suggested you just have to install "appy" from pip